# Why is my Vertex AI dataset not displayed?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I created a Vetex AI dataset in `us-central1` and confirm it exists using:

```
vertex_ai.TabularDataset.list()
```

When I look at the UI I don't see any datsets, but I see a region drop-down, but no `us-central1`. Why is that? (The project is the correct one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** there but at the beginning of the list, not with the other US ones.